# is my .htaccess correct for non-www to www AND to force https?

Tags: .htaccess

We are switching to HTTPS.

Our current .htaccess file has the following code to force non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now, for HTTPS this is my proposed addition:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

My question is - how do I merge - or combine - the non-www to www AND HTTPS? Or would I just keep the order as is above?

Thanks.

PS I have researched this but I don't seem to find any concise answer....

Answer (score 2):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Or without domain name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

I recommend you use the first. If indicate the domain name is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks.....seems simple enough. I see that the fourth line of the first rule forces https - so I guess that is all good....